# Nodejs open ppt, doc or any other files

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

I have been trying to execute any file in system and open it in the default Application of the system.

> For example I have **abc.doc** file, and i want to open it in Microsoft Word.

This code opens the URL in default browser.

```
var open = require('open');
    open('http://www.google.com', function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('The user closed the browser');
});
```

Any suggestion how do I open system files in default application via node js.

Comment: just launch a child process, passing the document path to an executable path.

Comment: is that not possible i just execute the **abc.doc** and it opens automatically in default Application?

Comment: on windows you can use START.EXE or CMD.EXE then the document to open it via the OS default app. maybe on other platforms too...

Comment: there is also **child_process.execFile** but dont know how to use. @dandavis can you please show some code how does it works

Comment: Are you trying to open the file on the server side (the computer currently running the node process)?  Or are you wanting to serve the file to a client so the client can open with the default application?

Comment: Serve the file to client and it automatically opens in default application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In windows you can simply give file path. But in linux or in mac os you need to prefix **xdg-open** as well to open in default application.

> Linux Code & Mac OS

```
shell.exec("xdg-open /home/file.extension", function (err, out, code)) { /* your statements */ });
```

> Windows Code

```
shell.exec("C:/file.extension", function (err, out, code)) { /* your statements */ });
```

Comment: that works, it is really what i needed. For both linux and windows

Answer (score 2):

> use **exec** from shelljs

Example given below:

```
var shell = require('shelljs');
shell.exec("D://yourdocument.pdf", function (err, out, code)) {
    if(err instanceof Error)
        throw err;
});
```

I hope it helps. Thanks.